# Memory overflow when calling XML-RPC

Tags: magento-1.9, xmlrpc

I am facing an issue with the XML-RPC interface. When I do a multicall, my Magento 1.9.4.0 setup starts running out of memory.

The call (a little shortened, the actual call is like 30 orders long):

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<methodCall>
<methodName>multiCall</methodName>
<params>
<param>
<value><string>TOKEN</string></value>
</param>
<param>
<value><array><data>
<value><array><data>
<value><string>sales_order.info</string></value>
<value><string>400000179</string></value>
</data></array></value>
<value><array><data>
<value><string>sales_order.info</string></value>
<value><string>300000024</string></value>
</data></array></value>
<value><array><data>
<value><string>sales_order.info</string></value>
<value><string>400000174</string></value>
</data></array></value>
<value><array><data>
<value><string>sales_order.info</string></value>
<value><string>200000205</string></value>
</data></array></value>
<value><array><data>
<value><string>sales_order.info</string></value>
<value><string>400000169</string></value>
</data></array></value>
<value><array><data>
<value><string>sales_order.info</string></value>
<value><string>500000018</string></value>
</data></array></value>
<value><array><data>
<value><string>sales_order.info</string></value>
<value><string>400000180</string></value>
</data></array></value>
..
<value><array><data>
<value><string>sales_order.info</string></value>
<value><string>200000199</string></value>
</data></array></value>
</data></array></value>
</param>
</params>
</methodCall>
```

The result from the logs:

> [Thu Feb 14 11:04:44.639767 2019] [cgi:error] [pid 963] [client x.x.x.x:40630] AH01215: PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of
>   2147483648 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 20480 bytes) in
>   /var/www/html/myshop/lib/Zend/XmlRpc/Value/Collection.php on line 47

I tried increasing the memory to 3GB, but then it just bails out at 3G. Upping it more is almost impossible, as the server only has 4G.

**Update** when narrowing it down, some orders get this error, and some others work fine.

What could cause this, and how to fix it?